# Route::resource method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have some problem with Route::resource That means consider following My Route

```
Route::resource('tasks','TasksController');
```

Now, I have following store method in My TaskController

```
public function store(Request $request, $id, Task $task)
    {


        $task = new Task;
        $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
        $task->body = $request->input('body');
        $task->assign          = $request->input('status');
        $task->priority        = $request->input('status');
        $task->duedate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input("date")));// $request->input('date');
        $task->project_id        = $id;



        $task->save();


    }
```

My problem is can I use Route::resource('tasks','TasksController'); for store method????

Comment: SO is not for `can I` questions, it's unclear what are you asking about.

Comment: oh..it is simple My problem is may I use Route::resource for store methos?

Comment: [resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers) automatically create multiple methods for you, including store

Comment: then plz consider My controller and is there some problem with store method?

Comment: you who should answer that question, what is the error/issue with your method ? what are you want to do?

Comment: I need store my data with store method in TaskController. but it is genereted "Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Controllers\TasksController::store() must be an instance of App\Task, none given" error message with above My TaskController and Route::resource

Answer (score 0):

The store method argument should look like this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
```

You don't have extra arguments like $id or $Task as you are creating a task in this method